# How To Implement SendBird Messaging SDK in Xamarin Android App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, sendbird

I am try to integrate SendBird Messaging SDK into my xamarin android app. I have integrated SendBird SDK in my app successfully, But I am not able to find last seen,Online status of the User(SendBird is returning MessagingChannel types with whom Chat already Happen).

If Any one have any solution Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen you have to follow the .Net library link https://docs.sendbird.com/dotnet